# Print json data to nested html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

from the server, I am receiving JSON category data. I want to print them as a table. if level1 category is the same just print once and print nested child categories. here is my JSON data.

```
const jsonData = [{
category_id: '010103',
level1: 'electronics',
level2: 'TV',
level3: 'samsung',
}, {
category_id: '010104',
level1: 'electronics',
level2: 'Pc',
level3: 'philips',
}, {
category_id: '010101',
level1: 'households',
level2: 'kitchen',
level3: 'table',
}];
```

and here is my source code

```
function printCategory(data) {
     let list = data['list'];
    console.log(list); 





    let uniqueLevels = {};
    if( list != null && list.length > 0 ) {

        $.each(list, function(index, value){
            if(value.level1 != null && (uniqueLevels[value.level1] == null || typeof uniqueLevels[value.level1] == 'undefined')) {
                uniqueLevels[value.level1] = {};
            }
            if( value.level2 != null && (uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2] == null || typeof uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2] == 'undefined') ) {
                uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2] = {};
            }
            if( value.level3 != null ) {
                if(uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2][value.level3] == null || typeof uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2][value.level3] == 'undefined') {
                    uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2][value.level3] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    uniqueLevels[value.level1][value.level2][value.level3] += 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    let tbodyHTML = '';
    $.each(uniqueLevels, function(level1_key, level1_data){
        $.each(level1_data, function(level2_key, level2_data){
            let level2Rows = '';
            let flagAddTR = false;
            let rowspanCount = 0;
            $.each(level2_data, function(level3_key, level3_data){
                rowspanCount += level3_data;
            });

            tbodyHTML += '<tr><td rowspan="'+ rowspanCount +'">'+ level1_key +'</td><td rowspan="'+ rowspanCount +'">'+ level2_key +'</td>';
            $.each(list, function(key, value){
                if( (value['level1'] == level1_key) && (value['level2'] == level2_key) ) {
                    if( level2Rows != '' ) {
                        flagAddTR = true;
                    }

                    if( flagAddTR ) {
                        level2Rows += '<tr>';
                    }
                    level2Rows += '<td>'+ value['level3'] +'</td><td>'+ value['category_id'] +'</td><td>'+value['meta_count']+'</td><td>'+moment(value['reg_date']).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')+'</tr>';
                }
            });
            tbodyHTML += level2Rows;
        });
    });

    $('#tbody').html(tbodyHTML);


}
```

i want to achieve this[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My program skips printing empty levels. if I have level1 but their child levels empty it should keep printing. if level1 has two different level2 categories print nested as level3 categories like on the picture.[image]

Comment: I would instead use `map` and/or `reduce` first to transform the JSON into the desired structure.  Then once I am happy with the result I would create another function, or another version of the function that embeds the data in html.  See [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Have a look at the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v05qyt7e/1/